# Offline playback on Android devices using Microsoft Playready SDK

Tags: android, video, sdk, playready

anyone knows how to playback a local video file on Android devices using Microsoft Playready SDK?

Any code example?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I am trying to do the same thing.

Comment: Hello Pascal, sorry about the delay, yes, we achieved this, but unfortunately i can not give you the exact details due Microsoft legals restrictions. But i can tell you that the solutions is simple. After download the encrypted (if your case) ISO base media file format, call the methods to retrieve the license, after you know you have the license in you device, you can try playback the video, not before or immediately. Hope this can help. Cheers!

Comment: Which library are you using for PlayReady playback on Android?

Comment: @Mike the Microsoft Playready SDK.

Comment: Has it been renamed? There is a short article here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/playready/overview/server-sdk
But I can't find the SDK itself...

Comment: This was a few years ago, not sure if you can find it publicly, since Playready is not open source or free lest say, I think you need to contact Microsoft somehow to get it. TBH, I do not remember how we go it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but it stills comes up in searches so in case anyone is still looking, the approach at a high level is:

- Your app requests the license when it is online, typically at the time the video is being downloaded.
- The license server will be configured to provide 'persistent' licenses for this content, or for this request for the content. The app and server will typically communicate some way so that the license server know this request is for content that is being download and may be viewed offline later.
- The DRM system, e.g. PlayReady, on the device will securely store the license - how it does this depends on the DRM and the device. The license is usually stored until its expiry time which is included in the metadata in the license.
- When your app plays the video in offline mode (or even when online) the video player recognises that the content is encrypted and checks to see if it has a valid key - so long as you are within the time window for your persistent license the DRM system will provide the key.

Microsoft provide this summary for PlayReady Persistent licenses (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/playready/overview/license-persistence):

> Persistent — Persistent licenses are stored in non-volatile memory (for example, in the local License Store on a hard drive or in a NAND memory) and last for the lifetime of the store or until a time-based restriction is reached. Generally, persistent licenses can either be used immediately or can be stored to be used in the future, and can be used to play back content for the life of the license. In addition, persistent licenses can be used to play back downloaded content while the device is offline.